# What is automatic constructor dependency injection and how does it work in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

As I'm reading further in Magento Books. I have learned a lot of its usages. But I am really curious why the team had moved using dependency injection.

Answer (score 1):

**Automatic Dependency Injection:**

In PHP application, if we inject the dependency with code that looks like this:

```
$dependency = new \[VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Model\Message;
$helper = new \[VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Model\Example($dependency);
```

However, with Magento 2's object system, we don't get to supply arguments

```
$helper = $this->getObjectManager()->create('[VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Model\Example');
```

Behind the scenes, the object manager will use **PHP's reflection** features to look at a class's __construct type hints/parameters, automatically instantiate the object for us, and then pass it into the constructor as an argument.

That's the beauty of Magento 2's automatic dependency injection system.

Answer (score 0):

Dependency injection is considered a best practice whereas creating a resource whenever, wherever needed as they did in Magento 1 is not best practice.